# render partial view as string in angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angualrjs to get a rendered partial view as a string in a controller (or service or whatever).

something like

```
var str = renderPartial('partials/foo.html', {/*scopeObj*/});
$scope.showMe = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, in your app run function, you can put the template cache to $templateCache:

```
angular.module("youApp", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("url/to/your/template1.html", 
        "<span>Template</span>");  // 'url/to/your/template1.html' is used to location the cache in angular
}]);
```

Then in your view or some where else, you can use the url(this wouldn't trigger http request now) to load the template you put in your $templateCache.

e.g. in html:

```
<div ng-include="url/to/your/template1"></div>
```

[Here is $templateCache document.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

By the way, this is how [angular-ui-bootstrap.js(at the bottom of this lib)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js) manager their template in lib. : )

Comment: Further more, they use grunt build to change html to js, and then wrap them in angular module to auto build all this template. [Angular-ui-bootstrap grunt file.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: thanks. i'm familiar with ng-include. i was more asking of a way to get a rendered view as a string in javascript and set it on a controller's $scope

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, you can pass html string to scope.property in controller. And in your view, you use 'ng-bind-html' to render it. [Here is document.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: yea. what i'm asking is how to get the html string rendered from a partial, while in the controller. see my example code. i'm looking for a render partial method.

Comment: but not a directive. something i can call in javascript

Comment: @bdwain Do you mean you already have a html loaded into your angularapp. And in your controller you want to get this string out, and then put this into you scope?

Comment: it might or might not be loaded into the app. i just have a partial, and an object that is its "scope", and i want to get a string of the html for that partial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$compile` service:

```
function someFunction($compile) {
  var element = $compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')({/*scopeObj*/});
}
```

And with `$templateCache` it could be just like what you want

```
function someFunction($compile $templateCache) {
  var element = $compile($templateCache.get('partials/foo.html'))({/*scopeObj*/});
}
```